# Ifconfig and route command on Android

Tags: android, linux, shell, ifconfig

I wondering whether exist way to get result of **ifconfig** and **route** commands result programmatically in Android device? Can I do this in non rooted device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Your code:**

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                /* you can print your active network via using below */
                Log.i("myNetworkType: ", connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName());
                WifiManager wifiManager= (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().WIFI_SERVICE);


                Log.i("routes ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getRoutes().toString());
                Log.i("domains ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDomains().toString());
                Log.i("ip address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getLinkAddresses().toString());
                Log.i("dns address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDnsServers().toString());



                if(connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    Log.i("myType ", "wifi");
                    DhcpInfo d =wifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
                    Log.i("info", d.toString()+"");
                }
                else if(connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
/* there is no EthernetManager class, there is only WifiManager. so, I used this below trick to get my IP range, dns, gateway address etc */

                    Log.i("myType ", "Ethernet");
                    Log.i("routes ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getRoutes().toString());
                    Log.i("domains ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDomains().toString());
                    Log.i("ip address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getLinkAddresses().toString());
                    Log.i("dns address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDnsServers().toString());

                }
                else {

                }
```

**Output**
[image]

You can't reach to know whether you are connected via wifi or network using `WifiManager` as `WifiManager` only deals with wifi. You have to use `ConnectivityManager`. I updated the code again where I merged `WifiManager` and `ConnectivityManager` to produce the result that you wanted.